# insert div at a particular position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

How to remove mynavbar and append to  main_table as the first element

```
<div id="mynavbar" > <div>Some content</div>  </div>

<div id="main_table"> </div>

<script>
if(condtion == 0)
{
    // How to remove mynavbar and insert into main_table div as the first element
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mynavbar').prependTo('#main_table').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mynavbar").prependTo("#main_table");
```

Answer (score 0):

for remove you can simply use...

```
$("#mynavbar").remove();
```

but once it will removed, it will not be there in your html..you should try something like this...

```
  var mynavbarHTML= $("#mynavbar").html();
   $("#mynavbar").remove();
  $("#main_table").prepend(mynavbarHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('#main_table').prepend (
>   $('#mynavbar').html() );
>
> $('#mynavbar').remove ();

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-jQuery answer for some variety.

```
var main = document.getElementById("main_table");
var secondary = document.getElementById("mynavbar");
if(main.firstChild)
{
    main.insertBefore(secondary, main.firstChild);
    console.log("first");
}else
{
    main.appendChild(secondary);
    console.log("last");   
}
```

EDIT: I'm amazed that there's 5 nearly identical answers. Yikes.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the purpose of removing an element after it's been moved. Counterproductive if anything.